# Can we use polymorphic relationships with Ember data?

Tags: ember.js, active-model-serializers

We have multiple types of 'widgets' that are available in groups and within rails we have a polymorphic relationship to return all of the widgets, regardless of type.

For example, we can call @group.widgets to return all of the different types of widgets, regardless of what might be in use.

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_widgets

  def widgets
    group_widgets.map { |m| m.widget }
  end
end

class GroupWidget < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :widget, polymorphic: true, dependent: :destroy
end
```

If I add polymorphic => true to the serializer. For example:

```
class GroupSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id,
             :parent_id,
             :title,
             :group_type

  has_many :widgets, :polymorphic => true
end
```

I seem to get a recursive loop, which ends with **SystemStackError (stack level too deep)**.

Am I missing a trick here, or is this just something that can't be done yet?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring it without the polymorphic declaration?

```
has_many :widgets
```

Also make sure each of your widget types has a serializer defined for them.